# Simplification results in different answer

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, geometry, inequality, complex-numbers

I want to find 
$$|1 + \frac{1}{2}z| \leq 1$$
so I use wolfram alpha and get the geometric area.

[image]

If I instead simplify it by setting $z = a + bi$ and obtaining 
$$|1 + \frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}bi| \leq 1$$
$$\sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{2}a)^2 + (\frac{1}{2}bi)^2}\leq 1$$

$$1 + a + a^2/4 + b^2/4 \leq 1$$
I get a different area, why? 
[image]

Comment: Isn't the first answer assuming that z is real ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first plot from Wolfram Alpha assumes that $z$ is real -- it's not smart enough to know that when there's a $z$ and no $x$ or $y$, you probably mean that it's a complex number.

The plot has $z$ on the horizontal axis and $|1+\frac12z|$ on the vertical axis. The shaded area doesn't really mean anything, but if you were to zoom in enough to see the ticks you'd see that the *real* solutions are the interval $[-4,0]$.

This is *also* the real part of the solution set you plot in the second graph. Nothing has actually changed; they're just different plots.

---

Instead of blindly plotting, it's more instructive to multiply each side of your inequality by $2$, giving
$$ |2+z| \le 2 $$
which you can rewrite as
$$ |z-(-2)| \le 2 $$
So you're looking for the points whose distance to $-2$ is less than or equal to $2$ -- or in other words for a **closed disk** with center $-2$ and radius $2$.

Answer (score 0):

The modulus requires taking the Complex Conjugate, not merely squaring and square rooting as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

In the first figure, Wolfram Alpha has assumed $z$ to be real. Therefore$$-2\le {z\over 2}\le 0$$or$$-4\le {z}\le 0$$which is reasonable.